# UE4 - How can I DOF-Blur the screen on pause?

Tags: unreal-engine4

That's what I'd like to know.
I don't understand the unreal engine scripting at all..

I know how to enable the blur manually, but how do I enable it on pause?

I have a Widget Blueprint with RESUME and EXIT buttons..
And when I open the menu, the background should be blurry.. now the menu is openable by pressing Tab(because in the editor ESC quits testing mode...)

So how do I make it blur on pause?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How did you do it? I would have taken a screenshot, apply a blur filter and use that as the overlay background.

If you've solved it by yourself, it would be nice if you post the solution anyway so other fellow developers might be able to enjoy it :)

Comment: Please note it is not necessary to add 'Solved' to your title. As you found out, Stack Overflow allows you to add your own answer and then accept it; then, the regular color highlight on the index pages indicates this question has an accepted answer.

Comment: @Jongware It was there before

Comment: Um – and I removed it. (And now, again.) **The presence of an accepted answer is already clearly indicated.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found the solution more than a week ago(I wasn't home) and I forgot to tell the answer to this question to all of you guys.

I made a few pictures telling you exactly what to do :).

[image: First step]

**Click the white arrow in the 'Make PostProcessSettings' to see all this options and check the 'Override Depth Of Field Method' checkbox.**
[image: Second]

**Now find the 'Method' option and change it to Gaussian.**
[image: Third and the last step]

**And you're done. You can see the results below this text.**

**In-Game:**
[image: Before]

**In Menu[By pressing ESC(you need to connect it to a Key Event). Btw you can make that blue shade in the widget blueprint(it's an image component with a transparent color)]:**
[image: After]

I hope I helped :).
Feel free to ask if you got any problems.

Comment: Is that node with all the options all part of Make PostProcessSettings? It looks different from mine, the Blendables option does not accept the array of widgets for example.

Comment: @Broxzier Yes.. I just noticed that I haven't explained that before... If you have any other problem feel free to ask.

Comment: I figured you nee to click the node, then allow this to be edited by selecting the editable options in the details window first. Do you by any chance know about a way of blurring out other widgets? I haven't been able to find anything about that.
It's also worth mentioning that this method doesn't work on all graphic cards (and lower graphics settings), since it uses Depth of Field, so a modal approach should always be used together with it.